# What is the affect of changing robots.txt file access permission?

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I want to change access permission of robots.txt file to 403. Just my static ip can access directly not any one. This position is true? why some people do that?

if it is true, What is the affect of this changes in my website seo and pages and other things?
if it is false, tell why? please answer with your experience and reference.

Comment: "Just my static ip can access directly not any one." - Why do _you_ want to do this? "This position is true? why some people do that?" - Oh, are you asking why?? Where did you get the idea for this? Which "some people do" this??

Answer (score 1):

> I want to change access permission of robots.txt file to 403. Just my static ip can access directly not any one.

This doesn't make sense. The only reason to have a `robots.txt` in the first place is to have it publicly accessible for search engines to determine if there are any URLs that should *not* be *crawled*.

Blocking `robots.txt` with a 403 HTTP response is effectively the same as not having a `robots.txt` file. ie. You are permitting unrestricted crawl access to your site.

If you don't want a `robots.txt` file (ie. you want *robots* to crawl everything) then simply don't include a `robots.txt` file and allow requests to 404. Alternatively, create an empty (or minimal) `robots.txt` to prevent a plethora of 404s in your access logs.

If you want to prevent *crawling* of certain URLs on your site then you need a `robots.txt` file and it *needs* to be publicly accessible. Access to this file should not be restricted.

> why some people do that?

I'm curious where you got the idea of this from?